# Find an ID in DOM using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, dom, vba

I need the excel vba to open a webpage and find a specific value within it and put it in cell A1. I am able to open the page but unable to get the number that I wanted. Please assist.

Current Code I have:

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium

Set Doc = appIE.Document
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "example.com"

With appIE
  .Navigate sURL
  .Visible = True

    Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
    Loop

    Set Elements = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each Element In Elements
        If Element.ID = "form-id" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Valu = Element.InnerText

        End If
    Next Element

Set Elements = Nothing
.Quit

End With
```

Below is the DOM explorer data from which it needs to find the highlighted number: 
[[image: Need to Capture Value : 830742[1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Valu = Element.InnerText
```

try

```
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Valu = Element.getAttribute("value")
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello xidgel, Your suggestion worked as it supposed to.   Thank  you so much!